# Rundeck Remote URL option to HTTPS with basic auth

Tags: url, certificate, basic-authentication, rundeck

I'm trying to use remote URL options in Rundeck 3.0.9, I found this similar post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#:~:text=Basic%20Auth%20with,is%20retrieved%20from%20...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#:%7E:text=Basic%20Auth%20with,is%20retrieved%20from%20...) .

So my questions are:

1. Where is it documented that the format to send user and password in an https request is like this  https://rundeck:test@myserver.com. ??
   I cannot find any https example in rundeck documentation.
2. When I try the remote URL option, I'm getting this error:
   Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

   Do you have any idea of how to get rid of this error?

I saw this same exact error when using http request plugin and it was fixed by just un-selecting the "Validate SSL certificate" option. Which makes me think that there should be some way to tell rundeck not to validate certificate for remote URL options. But I don't know how to do this.

Any ideas are very appreciated,
BR Sandra

Answer (score 0):

Add the remote server SSL certificate to java cacert like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/10426011) answer. However, consider that the remote option output must complain [these](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#requirements) requirements at least.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried but still cannot make it work.
I'd still like to know if the format user:pwd@urtl is the right way to send the authentication?

Comment: Yes, my answer shows the way to add to the trust store, the best way is to add the remote server cert to the java cacert. My link is updated now :)